# How do I solve this particular differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't even know what 'type' of equation is, or how I should go about solving it
$$
yy'' + \left(y'\right)^2 - \left(y'\right)^3\ln(y) = 0
$$

Comment: First thought: $$(yy')' = yy'' + (y')^2$$

Comment: Second thought: divide by some power of $y$ and of $y'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is autonomous and you can reduce the order by setting $y' = w(y)$, which leads to

$$yww' + w^2 - w^3 \ln(y) = 0, \qquad w = w(y).$$

$w = 0$ is a solution, otherwise

$$yw' = w^2 \ln(y) - w,$$

which is a well-known Bernoulli equation with solution

$$w(y) = \frac{1}{Cy + \ln(y) + 1}.$$

In order to get $y = y(x)$, you now have to solve

$$\int \frac{\mathrm dy}{w} = \int \mathrm dx,$$

which should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{(yy')'}{(yy')^2}=\frac{y'\ln y}{y^2}=\left(\frac1y\right)'\ln\frac1y.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$yy'' + \left(y'\right)^2 - \left(y'\right)^3\ln(y) = 0$$
Consider $x'$ instead of $y'$

The equation becomes:
$$-yx''+x'=\ln y$$
Substitute $z=x'$ and solve

Or write it like:
$$\left ( \frac {x'}{y}\right )'=- \frac {\ln y}{y^2}$$
Integrate.

---

Another way:

$$yy'' + \left(y'\right)^2 - \left(y'\right)^3\ln(y) = 0$$
$$(yy')'=\left(y'\right)^3\ln(y) $$
$$\frac {(yy')'}{(y'y)^2}=\frac {y'}{y^2}\ln(y) $$
$$\frac {d(yy')}{(y'y)^2}=\ln(y) \frac {dy}{y^2}$$
I let you continue.